# print out found result of regexp in RS

Tags: regex, printing, awk, record, separator

Hi all can you help me print out result of regexp in RS ?

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="--[0-9a-zA-Z]+--"} /pattern/' awk-test.txt
```

pattern="--[0-9a-zA-Z]+--" can be equal --95700e1b-- or --0dcaf754-- or else
awk print out block of text between RS, how can I print found RS too?

PS sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Use [[:alnum:]] instead of [[0-9a-zA-Z]] for portability, especially in non-native English speaking countries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `RS` can only be a single character in a portable `awk` script, I'll assume you are using `gawk`.  In that case, you can reference `RT`, which will contain the text that matched the regular expression specified in `RS`.  (`RT` is the record terminator, so it is the value of the text that matches `RS` at the end of the current record rather than the beginning.)

Comment: Thanks solved!)
gawk 'BEGIN {RS="--[0-9a-zA-Z]+--"} /pattern/ {print $0; print RT}' awk-test.txt